# how to refresh a xib view?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have a xib file with some UILabels.
In 
`- (void)viewDidLoad`
I send a request to fetch JSON data from the server and in 
`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`
 I want to put the text I extracted from the JSON String into the Labels. I know that I get the Information I need from the JSON String since i can NSLog it, but it won't show in the Labels. I tried 
`[self loadView];` 
at the end without success. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you connect the labels in the XIB file to their definition in the header file (.h)?? if yes use the following--> if you have a label called label123 you can update the text using label123.text=myJSONVal

Comment: I'm sure it's connected since i can change the Labels text in - (void)viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply set a label's text, it should automatically refresh it:

```
myLabel.text = @"some text";
```

Comment: I use self.itemtitle.text = [value objectForKey:@"title"]; it doesn't refresh though.

Comment: try to NSLog (@"%@", [value objectForKey:@"title"];);

Comment: It sounds like your nib connections are not fully operational. You should look into correcting your connections.

Comment: NSLog shows exactly what i want, I will redo the connections again although the rest of the view works correctly

Comment: I reconnected them all again but it still won't show the text, I also created a button with a function that puts something in the label which works. The only part that can't change the label is ´- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection´ but I know it gets executed since it shows the NSLogs....

Comment: Check your reference to that label in the connectionDid... method to be different than nil. Make an `NSLog(@"%@", label);` inside the method.

Comment: NSLog shows <UILabel: 0x6b47d80; frame = (171 54; 129 21); text = 'Test-title'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6b48730>>    the text-tag shows exactly what i want but it's not showing in the simulator